# Netty in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, netty, oracle12c

For testing purposes I try to run Netty 3.9.0 echo server example (can be found in Netty examples) inside Oracle database.

It starts correctly and I can see service running on port (with nmap), but whenever try to send message I get below exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: recv() failed, errno = 104
Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:33)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:166)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
kgskupdbalance:  time_used[58236668] greater than threshold[30000000] current_time[12380314910] time_start[12322078242]
```

Remarks:

- Code works when run outside (in shell)
- privileges are granted (and no other exception found)
- My 1st suspect would be java.nio in database

Somebody has explanation ?

NOTE: Just to repeat, it's just for testing purposes.
Do not ask for motivation :-)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes in zone which is not supported (native methods).